# SQL CLR function returning error trying to use context to create table and insert rows

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I am running on SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5, trying to build a CLR function that creates a table and inserts results into it using the context connection.

I'm getting the error:

> An error occurred in RunFetchXML: Data access is not allowed in this context.  Either the context is a function or method not marked with DataAccessKind.Read or SystemDataAccessKind.Read, is a callback to obtain data from FillRow method of a Table Valued Function, or is a UDT validation method.

**UPDATE:**
I was able to get past the error above, I found that the assembly didn't update as expected after I added the DataAccessKind.Read attribute, so after updating that I tried again and got this error:

```
An error occurred in RunFetchXML: Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'CREATE TABLE' within a function.
```

I'm trying to set up a CLR function that will take in `FetchXML` as an input string, the CLR function will need to take that `FetchXML` and query an external system, then create a table and dump the results into it. I don't think I can use a table-valued function with `FillRow`, etc, because I would need to be able to handle whatever was defined in the `FetchXML`, which means the end result could be anything, its not a fixed data structure.

So what I want to do is from within the CLR make a connection back to SQL Server using the current context, create a table that supports the fields returned by the `FetchXML`, and then dump the query results into the table.

I'm running in to the above mentioned error trying this, and I'm not sure this is even possible yet, any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current code for the CLR function, this is simplified to the point of just trying to create an empty table, and return a string result with "Success" or the error message, that's where I'm getting the above error from:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Retrieve

   <SqlFunction(DataAccess:=DataAccessKind.Read)> _
   Public Shared Function RunFetchXML(pstrFetchXML As SqlString) As SqlString
      Dim lstrResult As SqlString
      Try
         Using lsqlConn As New SqlConnection("context connection=true")
            lsqlConn.Open()
            Using lsqlCmd As New SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE #test (vchField1 varchar(200), iField2 int)", lsqlConn)
               lsqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
               lsqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
         End Using

         lstrResult = "Success"
      Catch ex As Exception
         lstrResult = "An error occurred in RunFetchXML: " + ex.Message
      End Try
      Return lstrResult
   End Function
End Class
```

And here's the pertinent portion of the SQL commands I am using to register this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [TestAssembly]
FROM 'C:\Mssql\CLR\TestAssembly.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION RunFetchXML(@pstrFetchXML nvarchar(MAX)) RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME TestAssembly.[TestAssembly.Retrieve].RunFetchXML
GO

Grant Execute on RunFetchXML TO Public;
```

I run this command to test it and get the error message as the return value:

```
DECLARE @vchOutput nvarchar(MAX)
EXEC @vchOutput = dbo.RunFetchXML['test']
SELECT @vchOutput
```

Am I just missing something here or is it not possible to write (create a table and insert to it) from a CLR function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions, whether T-SQL or SQLCLR, cannot modify state of the server. There is a whole list of things that cannot be done, such as any `SET` commands, calling `NEWID()`, etc. Check out the MSDN page for [Create User-defined Functions (Database Engine)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx#Restrictions) for the list of "Limitations and Restrictions". The only difference for SQLCLR functions is that they can execute T-SQL stored procedures, but only if they in turn don't violate any of those restrictions.

So you could stay with using a Function but change the `SqlConnection` to use a real/external connection as that will be seen as any other client connection and not have such restrictions. Of course, this would block your ability to create a local temporary table as that temp table would be on a different Session and would disappear once the Function ends.

Instead, switch the Function to be a Stored Procedure:

- Procs have no such restrictions. The only real downside is that they are not nearly as easy to use in queries or interact with their results.
- This would allow you to create a local temp table, though it might not exist once the proc is done since it is being created in a subprocess, and just like Dynamic SQL that creates a temporary object, they don't exist once that `EXEC` ends.
- You wouldn't really need to create a temp table since Stored Procs can return dynamic result sets that are not hard-coded into the app code.

---

Additional notes:

- `dbo.RunFetchXML['test']` is an odd syntax, even for executing a function like a stored procedure (which is fine, but still odd syntax for the parameter). It should be `SET @vchOutput = dbo.RunFetchXML('test');`
- What does any of this have to do with XML? And if you are just returning a result set to the client, there is an even easier way using `SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend()` where you can submit a `SqlCommand` that has a `SqlConnection` to the remote machine. As long as you don't need to intercept the results to do anything with them, this would get around the need to define the result set structure.

Comment: thanks for the thorough response, I updated my OP with a new error msg, which supports what you're saying about the restrictions.  To fill in more details, the reason I'm taking in FetchXML is to execute that query against Dynamics CRM online, this CLR function would have to reference the CRM SDK assembly to execute the query and get the results back.  So that's the reason for the xml and for the dynamic structure of the result set, sorry for being light on the details in the OP.  You make a good point about the temp table ,I was hoping to keep that so the table name could be an input param.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the CLR stored proc option, I'll have to research that.  Also, I'm interested in trying the ExecuteAndSend, but I'm not sure how that would work because I will most likely have to process the result set.  The results from the FetchXML would most likely be some sort of generic List(Of Something) that I will have to process and insert.  One other option I'm wondering about is if INSERT statements are allowed, I might be able to pre-create the table before coming into the CLR function, or as you suggested, use a separate connection and a "real" table.

Comment: Re: the syntax of the function call, I tried `dbo.RunFetchXML('test')` but that gave me an error `Incorrect syntax near 'test'.`  not sure what the problem is with that, but brackets worked.  Also, the reason for UNSAFE was because I will eventually need to reference the CRM SDK dll, unless EXTERNAL_ACCESS will work still when third-party dlls are dependencies?

Comment: @AaronKoehler I updated the first paragraph with info about function restrictions. And I realized the issue with the odd syntax of the `[` and `]` and updated that bullet point in the notes. Regarding wanting to communicate with Dynamics CRM: 1) that is critical info needed to help on this issue and should be in the question, and 2) have you searched for that? It sounds familiar. Maybe someone else has done it? `ExecuteAndSend` won't work if it's not a SQL query. INSERT would be allowed in a proc, or a function using a regular/external connection. UNSAFE might not be needed; try without first.